# how can I replace characters in a string while matching the case of the original string?

Tags: java, text, case-sensitive

basically I want:

```
HellO MY NamE IS BilL
```

say we want to replace name with tag
so the output is:

```
HellO MY tag IS BiLL
```

I have seen comparisons on this website and the common method of making the whole string lowercase then doing the comparison but if I do this then I lose the case value of the original string. Here is a more broad example:

```
text=text.replaceAll(words, replacementWords);
```

also `.compareToIgnoreCase(str)` does not work because it is comparing strings

Comment: Please let me know if i forgot a detail and I will fix it promptly

Comment: To clear up, in the second example, words and replacement words are variables of type String.

Comment: Show the value of `words` and `replacementWords`, and then tell us what you want to happen.

Comment: Your title and example are inconsistent, and your input and output are inconsistent.  The title implies that the output should be `Hello MY Tag IS BilL`, and the word `BilL` is `BiLL` in the output.  Your question cannot be answered in its current form.

Comment: @JimGarrison I didn't even catch that, and it's probably just a typo.  No need to serial downvote everything :-)

Comment: @JimGarrison yes I know that, thats why I gave the example because the wording was confusing and I didnt know how to word it otherwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing a case insensitive replace all:

```
String input = "HellO MY NamE IS BilL";
String output = input.replaceAll("(?i)\\bname\\b", "tag");
System.out.println(output);

HellO MY tag IS BilL
```

We should also place word boundaries around `name` while searching, so as to avoid an incorrect replacement, e.g. doing a replacement on `surname`, which is not what we want.

Comment: This works for the first example but not the second, it spits out 8 error messages

Comment: _Second_ example?  I see only one example in your question.  Maybe you forgot to add it?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the second example is as follows: 


`text=text.replaceAll(words, replacementWords);`

Comment: I forgot the plus sign. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

This will search for "name" in a case-insensitive manner and replace it with "tag":-

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?i)name", "tag");
```